# Wordpress: previous_post_link() sits on top, after div "entry-content", no matter where I place it

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have installed a plugin which is custom post type, I am trying to use the `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` to get previous and next posts.

It is working fine but the only problem is that I am placing it in my 4th div container where as it always sits on top of page right after div `"entry-content"`.

Is it a known issue?

Here is the piece of code:

```
function some_function () {

global $post;

    if ('team' == get_post_type() && is_single() && in_the_loop()) {
        $fields = WPMTPv2_OPTIONS()->fields;
        $meta = WPMTPv2_FIELDS($post->ID);

        $tmp = '<div id="wpmtp-single-wrap">';
        $tmp .= '<div class="wpmtp-vcard">';
        $tmp .= '<div class="wpmtp-vcard-left">';

        $tmp .= wpmtpv2_featured_img($post->ID);

        $previous   = previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="wpmtp-gonext">view next</div>');
        $next       = next_post_link('%link', '<div class="wpmtp-goback">go back</div>');
//        $tmp .= '<a href=""><div class="wpmtp-goback">go back</div></a>';
//        $tmp .= '<a href=""><div class="wpmtp-gonext">view next</div></a>';

        $tmp .= $previous;
        $tmp .= $next;

        $tmp .= '</div>';

...........
..........
..........
........

return $tmp;

}
```

If I place the commented html code instead or previous and next functions, it works fine. Which mean that html and css are right in place, and the problem is in the functions I guess.

And this is what I get after inspecting it in firebug:

```
<article .....>
<h2 .....></h2>
<div class="meta"></div>
    <div class="entry-content">

        <a href="link to next" rel="prev">
                    <div class="wpmtp-gonext">view next</div>
                </a>
    <a href="link to previous" rel="next">
        <div class="wpmtp-goback">go back</div>
    </a>
    <div id="wpmtp-single-wrap">
        <div class="wpmtp-vcard">
            <div class="wpmtp-vcard-left">
.....
....
....
....
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: We can't help without code...

Comment: @KrunalShah I have added the code. Kindly do check it.

Comment: @DavidGard I have added the code snippet, you may check it and see if it is helpful

Comment: Can you post your code after it compiles from the browser thanks

Comment: @LJ-C you can clearly see that I have placed it in this div <div class="wpmtp-vcard-left">, after image but it sits above, even above the parent wrap div

Comment: @atif, I can see that but I would like to see where you have closed the tags and if they are closed. You also might have issue in your CSS, possibly incorrectly used float: / position:

Comment: Even your code shows that your controls are outside your <div> wrapps that is why its overlapping... You need to have then inside this <div> <div id="wpmtp-single-wrap">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43784/discussion-between-atif-and-lj-c)

Comment: No, Kindly pay attention to it, controls are in the <div class="wpmtp-vcard-left"> which is 2nd child of wrap div

Comment: Hmm, I think you might be looking at something wrong. The rendered code shows its nested with in main container not with in the wrap so you didn't nest them properly. When you run your site look at the code and you will see how it was rendered.   <div class="entry-content">

        <a href="link to next" rel="prev">
                    <div class="wpmtp-gonext">view next</div>
                </a>
    <a href="link to previous" rel="next">
        <div class="wpmtp-goback">go back</div>
    </a>
    <div id="wpmtp-single-wrap">

Comment: Yes, you are right that rendered code shows like it is not nested properly but kindly do have a look at the code where it is clearly under the <div> and even if I place any html rather than the functions, it works fine .i.e. it sits fine under the left div under image. so there is a problem with the function.

Comment: Yes sometimes wordpress renders the code very wired, I can't explain why but it does. I had similar problems with links it wouldn't nest them with in the <p> but rather outside so I had to break it all down into 3-4 steps to get it to function correctly.

Comment: Is there any other way, I can get the links of next and previous posts? so I can just add the links to html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code:

```
    <?php
    function some_function () {

    global $post;

        if ('team' == get_post_type() && is_single() && in_the_loop()) {
            $fields = WPMTPv2_OPTIONS()->fields;
            $meta = WPMTPv2_FIELDS($post->ID);
    ?>
            <div id="wpmtp-single-wrap">
               <div class="wpmtp-vcard">
                  <div class="wpmtp-vcard-left">
                     <?php echo wpmtpv2_featured_img($post->ID); ?>
                     <div class="wpmtp-goback"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( ' go back', 'twentyeleven' ),TRUE ); ?></div>
                     <div class="wpmtp-gonext"><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'view next', 'twentyeleven' ),TRUE ); ?></div>
                         <?php      
                         // replace **twentyeleven** with your theme name
                         //or try with this line
                         //previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="wpmtp-gonext">view next</div>');   
                         //next_post_link('%link', '<div class="wpmtp-goback">go back</div>');                       
                        ?>               
            </div>
    <?php        
    .........
    .........
    ........

    return $tmp;

    }
```

or best to try this plugin : [wp-pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)

This plugin provides the wp_pagenavi() template tag which generates fancy pagination links.

thanks

Comment: But what it will return cuz $tmp is not define. It has assigned nothing throughout the scope.

Comment: i tried it that way, $tmp .= '<div class="wpmtp-goback">' . previous_post_link( '%link', __( ' go back', 'dcp' ),TRUE ) . '</div>'; but it didn't work and by removing TRUE from the end, it repeated the same behaviour

Comment: please try with removing $temp

Comment: remove it just from the previous and next link functions or throughout the function as you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: remove it from through out the function, as i have mention it above

Comment: Thanks much Krunal Shah :) It indeed fixed the problem but can you explain why was this happening?

Comment: even i don't know :), but i was messed up with same in past :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43830/discussion-between-krunal-shah-and-atif)